# Losing connection to powered USB hub

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb, tethering

Background (not a development question): I'm developing an application which allows multiple android devices to interact.  I am trying to tether the phones through a powered USB hub to run some simulation tests.  In order to use the phones through USB tethering, I have to shell in and do some configuring.  Typically, I leave the phones plugged in overnight, or else I lose these configurations and I have to redo them.

For some reason, when I get in the next morning, some of the lights above the ports on the powered USB hub are off.  The phones connected to these ports are no longer tethered.  In order to resolve this, I have to disconnect the USB cable, reconnect it, re-tether the phone, and redo the configurations.  This is not so inconvenient for 1-2 phones, but I will soon be testing my application with upwards of 30-50 phones.  I will probably be writing a script to configure the phones, but I would ideally not be running this script every day.

I am currently using Nexus S phones with Cyanogenmod v 10.1.0 (based on 4.2.2 I believe), but I do not think this issue is phone dependant.

Is there any setting on the phones that I can set to keep the phones tethered indefinitely?  As far as I can tell, the phones all have the same settings for going to sleep/screen locking. I am really not sure why they are disconnecting, but I am pretty sure it is not the USB hub nor the USB cables.

Update: I forgot to mention that I suspend my computer (Ubuntu 13.04) , but when I return from suspending my session, only some of the phones are powered.  I marked my phones before I left for the weekend, and when I came back the same ones that were powered when I unsuspended my session last time are powered now.  So I think this is an issue with phone settings.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if only one phone is plugged into the hub?

Comment: I haven't noticed, but today for example there were 2 phones plugged in and 1 was disconnected.  Yesterday there were 4 plugged in, and 2 were disconnected.  Unfortunately, the issue doesn't seem to happen until I leave for the day, as I can't just not touch the phones for hours as I am using them.